# GMailSender not caching any exception, although there's no connection

Tags: android, android-wifi

Im trying to use GMailSender to send an email right from my app

My fragment:

public class updateFragment extends SherlockFragment {

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_layout, group, false);





    Button buttonsubmit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonsubmit);
    buttonsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {   
                GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("test@gmail.com", "test");
                sender.sendMail("Update info",   
                        "",   
                        "test@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com");
                Toast.makeText(updateFragment.this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Info Submitted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

            } catch (Exception e) {   
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
                Toast.makeText(updateFragment.this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Please make sure that you have an internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




        }

    });

    return v;

}
}
```

GMailSender:

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}   

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}   
}
```

It works OK, but if there was no connection , it would appear like it was working OK, i mean the toast would say "Info Submitted Successfully", why isnt it causing or catching the exception??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because
`GMailSender.sendMail` is already catching the exception. Remove try catch block inside `GMailSender.sendMail` you will get the exception.